# How to download file from a local server cache windows server

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, smb

How could I download a files from a local server cache address path I was given? Not sure how to do this on windows server:

```
Link to local sever cache: \\sdgd07mjbvbw2\Users\BuildUser\Downloads
```

Here there is a bunch of stuff I need to download.

Not even sure what the double slashes mean? How could I get to this in Windows? And then download it. I guess the equivalent would be the smb on Mac. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: There is a lot about your environment that we don't know so I am not comfortable providing this as an answer, but assuming that there is a computer named sdgd07mjbvbw2 and that it has a share named users, and that the sub-folders exist, then this would do what I think you want in powershell: copy-item \\sdgd07mjbvbw2\Users\BuildUser\Downloads\*.* c:\temp\

Comment: Thanks EBGreen, how could I see a list of items in that directory? Before I download I want to make sure what I'm downloading

Comment: Get-childItem \\sdgd07mjbvbw2\Users\BuildUser\Downloads\*.*